# Is there a difference between using pmount and mount?

Tags: linux, command-line, mount, fstab

Is there any difference between using `pmount` to mount a device (e.g., USB drive) and using `mount` with `user` in the 4th column of `/etc/fstab`?

Essentially, is the only purpose of pmount to allow the mounting of a device as `user`, either without an `fstab` entry or to a mount point not specified by `fstab`... or are there greater differences?

Thank You.

Comment: I'm thinking `pmount` is distro-specific - running Zenwalk 6.4, I can find no mention of it in my `man` pages. I use the `user` argument, by the way.

Comment: @new123456 it might be.  It didn't come standard on xubuntu, I had to install it as a package.  I used to use it a lot but I to just set up `fstab` the way I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*From http://pmount.alioth.debian.org/*

> pmount is a wrapper around the standard mount program which permits normal users to mount removable devices without a matching /etc/fstab entry.

So yes its only purpose is to allow normal users to mount removable drives.